# time complexity of the acc function in scheme?

Tags: scheme, complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have been trying to find a tight bound time complexity for this function with respect to just one of the arguments. I thought it was O(p^2) (or rather big theta) but I am not sure anymore.

```
(define (acc p n)
  (define (iter p n result)
    (if (< p 1) 
        result
        (iter (/ p 2) (- n 1) (+ result n))))
  (iter p n 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

@sarahamedani, why would this be O(p^2)? It looks like O(log p) to me. The runtime should be insensitive to the value of `n`.

You are summing a series of numbers, counting down from `n`. The number of times `iter` will iterate depends on how many times `p` can be halved without becoming less than 1. In other words, the position of the leftmost '1' bit in `p`, minus one, is the number of times `iter` will iterate. That means the number of times `iter` runs is proportional to `log p`.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, it is in the set of programs O(p^2), speaking purely from the technical definition.  It's just that it belongs also to a much smaller set, and we're trying to convince the OP that O(p^2) is way, way too loose of an upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to eyeball it, or go from it more systematically.  Assuming we're doing this from scratch, we should try build a recurrence relation from the function definition.

We can assume, for the moment, a very simple machine model where arithmetic operations and variable lookups are constant time.

Let `iter-cost` be the name of the function that counts how many steps it takes to compute `iter`, and let it be a function of `p`, since `iter`'s termination depends only on `p`.  Then you should be able to write expressions for `iter-cost(0)`. Can you do that for `iter-cost(1)`, `iter-cost(2)`, `iter-cost(3)`, and `iter-cost(4)`?

More generally, given an `p` greater than zero, can you express `iter-cost(p)`?  It will be in terms of constants and a recurrent call to `iter-cost`.  If you can express it as a recurrence, then you're in a better position to express it in a closed form.